# How to run iPhone program with Zombies instrument?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, instruments

I'm running XCode 3.2 on Snow Leopard and I'm trying to run the Zombies instrument against my app but the selection is grayed out and I don't know why. I know about the NSZombieEnabled environment variable. I have that set to YES on my application. I'm not sure if this matters, but, the app is an app that I started developing on Leopard with the previous version of XCode. Here is a screenshot of what my menu looks like:

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: I have never seen the Zombies tool, so I can't tell you much.  What I do know is that some of the tools work when running on a device but not on the simulator.  You could try that.

Comment: Tried that, still not enabled.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I followed the single answer here and like Anthony D my Zombies option is still grayed out.

Comment: I noticed that the Zombies instrument shows up after hitting Products > Profile when I set the scheme to iPhone Simulator, but if I set it to device Zombies is gone.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**You need to launch the Instruments application with the Zombies instrument from outside of XCode**

This is how you can do it:

The Instruments application is usually located inside `/Developer/Applications/`, but you can also use Spotlight to find it.

When Instruments starts you should be presented with a screen that asks you to choose a template for the new Trace Document.

Select: `iPhone Simulator > Memory > Zombies`

Next you need to choose a target.

Go to: `Chose target > Chose target > Chose target...`

Now you need to select the application file:
`<Path to your iPhone project>/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/<Application name>`
and press `Chose`.

Now you are all set.

To launch you application press the `Record` button.

A few **Side Notes**:

- I used XCode 3.2.3 on Mac OS X 10.6.3, but I believe it works the same on previous versions.
- The Zombies instrument only works with the simulator.
- The Zombies instrument cannot be used with the Leaks instrument because all the zombies would appear as leaks.
- I would also like to know why the menu in XCode is grayed out.

Answer (score 7):

Are you sure you're setting it in the right place? I mean, it is a runtime tuneable, not compile time. Just be sure you're setting it in the right place and try again.

Go to Project -> Edit Active Executable
Click Arguments
Click + in the "Variables to be set in the environment" section
Enter NSZombieEnabled in the Name column and YES in the Value column.
Make *sure* the checkmark for the NSZombieEnabled entry is checked.

Comment: That's not Instruments's Zombies functionality; it's the older built-into-Foundation zombie feature. Instruments's version is more powerful.

Answer (score 2):

As said by Apple engineers, most items under Run with Performance Tool need dTrace support, but dTrace is not available for iOS yet, not even for simulators.

However, strangely, you can manually set up a template in Instruments to test zombies, as described by @florin