# IPhone tracking memory overwrites

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, memory-management

I have an issue where i call a function on an object in one of my classes but at the time I call its holding a reference to a different object type and its a different type everytime, so i receive messages as so `-[UIGestureRecognizerTarget stopConnection]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b23710` and the types are always UI type classes.

So this leads me to believe something is overriding memory somewhere and I can't track it down! It only happens when i delete a row from a UITableView, and thought that maybe this is deleting something before im ready for it too but nothing seems to have dealloced before im calling this function!

Is there anyway I can track when a value at memory address changes, or what would be the best way to track down what is changing the reference of my object in XCode??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a memory management issue. An object is being dealloced and another is being put in its place while you're still holding a reference to the old one. You can [run the app with Zombies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417782/how-to-run-iphone-program-with-zombies-instrument) and see what object it is, but it's probably whatever object was being shown in your table view.

Comment: Hi Chuck, thank you very much for that advice it is a step in the right direction! The zombie stuff shows me a release happening that shouldn't be, but putting a breakpoint on the code where the release happens never gets hit but the error still happens! so I don't know if the zombie stuff is wrong or how a function can be called but the breakpoint missed? Either way it would still be a huge help to track the memory address if possible?