# Error: *** -[CALayer retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xdaa54d0

Tags: iphone, calayer, retain, retaincount, exc-bad-access

I am working on simple iphone application.  where i am working on two views.  I pushed the other view controller first and when i am removing the current view as to go back to the old view controller i am getting [CALayer retain]. `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS`.

In gdb, i tried backtrace command to see the problem which i have given below, but i am not able to find any.  If anyone can help me out with this it will be great.

(gdb) backtrace

```
#0  0x02e21434 in ___forwarding___ ()
#1  0x02e209f2 in __forwarding_prep_0___ ()
#2  0x02dc7f58 in CFRetain ()
#3  0x02dc7a65 in CFArrayCreate ()
#4  0x02dfe043 in -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] ()
#5  0x0296eda3 in -[CALayerArray copyWithZone:] ()
#6  0x02ea380a in -[NSObject copy] ()
#7  0x004f742a in -[UIView dealloc] ()
#8  0x00214cb2 in NSPopAutoreleasePool ()
#9  0x004d3698 in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
#10 0x035fe17c in PurpleEventCallback ()
#11 0x02df289c in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#12 0x02df18a8 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#13 0x035fc89d in GSEventRunModal ()
#14 0x035fc962 in GSEventRun ()
#15 0x004d1372 in UIApplicationMain ()
#16 0x00002074 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff020) at /Users/jtong/Desktop/Elle/main.m:14
```

Thanks,
   Aby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're also explicitly releasing something that you've already autoreleased.

Comment: i figure out the problem it was in dealloc.  I was not releasing in proper way.  Thanks for the repsone.

Comment: in dealloc.  By mistake for one object i have kept [arr dealloc].. instead of [arr release].  This was causing a problem.

Comment: Yup. And all the stacktrace tells you is that it is something visible (CALayer), so it could be a UILabel, UIImageView, etc. Annoyingly vague. Tip: search for 'release' and check that you have a matching retain or alloc.

Answer (score 0):

Use Instruments and enable Zombies. This will trace where each object was retained and released and will hell you diagnose where the extra release is occurring.

[How to run iPhone program with Zombies instrument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417782/how-to-run-iphone-program-with-zombies-instrument)

Comment: Hey paul i tried this but this is not working.  When i started my application with performance tool it is crashing..